# How to Increase File Upload Size In Apache Config

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Hy Guys! I'm struggling in this configuration problem, because i'm trying to increase the file upload size capacity in Apache configuration, but idk how to do it exactly. I found this article talking about that but want to know the correct way change the .htaccess.

https://brightwhiz.com/increase-file-upload-size-apache/

I'm trying to resolve a problem in php (laravel) that i cant upload files bigger than 5MB, so I found this solution in this article. What's the correct way to config my .htaccess to do it?

I've tried these configs

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    <Directory "/var/www/html/assets">
        LimitRequestBody 67108864
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/html/assets">
    LimitRequestBody 67108864
</Directory>
```

Comment: Why do you show what appears to be the same `.htaccess` file twice?

Comment: you can increase the same in php.ini file. update parameters `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to the limit you need

Comment: Or follow the link at the botton of the page you link us to where there is another page that tells you how to alter the PHP settings from the `.htaccess` file. [**Look and ye shall find**](https://brightwhiz.com/increase-maximum-file-upload-size-php/)

Comment: I just want to show the two different ways I've configured the .htaccess

Comment: @Bhavik I've tried all that configs but without success, and I can see this in the php_info()

Comment: after modifying php.ini file, you need to restart your apache service. have you done that?

Comment: @Bhavik I forgot to tell you guys that I'm dockering the PHP, so after changing the php.ini file, I've just restarted the container.

Comment: Here are the parameters that I changed in php.ini, you can see in my php_info()
 
https://imgur.com/MQRHWg9

https://imgur.com/nkNNc02

https://imgur.com/btQ7u3b

https://imgur.com/RnTqy4F

Answer (score 6):

The **upload_max_filesize** and the **post_max_size** settings in the **php.ini** need to changed to support larger files than the php default allowed size.

set **upload_max_filesize** to the maximum size of file which need to be uploaded.

Set **memory_limit** to amount of memory needed for the php script to run and **max_execution_time** to the time in seconds required to run the script.

> Note : And from now the ini stored in folder something like this
> /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize=30M
post_max_size=31M
memory_limit = 100M
max_execution_time = 120
```

> Note : Don't forgot to restart the apache server
> If you can't save the php.ini file than you have to give permission to that particular one file. ( don't give permission to whole folder )

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I've tried that, just sharing my upload images about this config here:

https://imgur.com/MQRHWg9
https://imgur.com/nkNNc02
https://imgur.com/btQ7u3b
https://imgur.com/RnTqy4F

Comment: You have to search "max_file_uploads" and "upload_max_filesize" for your solution.
upload_max_filesize is use for you can upload larger file in file upload.
max_file_uploads is use for increase no of file.

Comment: my "max_file_uploads" has 20 in your value, But I'm trying to upload a 5MB file and not working, so Idk if need to change the "max_file_uploads".

Comment: You have to change this parameter in php.ini "upload_max_filesize".
Default is 2MB, you can increase as per your need.

Don't forgot to restart the server.

Comment: I've tried it, I changed "upload_max_filesize" to 128MB but still not working. Here's my imgur link https://imgur.com/MQRHWg9 with the php_info() config

Comment: @rainangramacho - can you tell what exactly error you are getting while uploading a file. you can turn on error_reporting to check the same